# Find all syscall in statically Arm Binary

Tags: linux, arm, static-analysis, ida-plugin, syscall

What is the easy and fast way to find all syscall in statically Arm binary ?

Is there any Ida plugin that do that?

Answer (score 1):

In `ARM` the syscalls are either [Supervisor call](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/ar01s02s07.html) or [Software interrupt](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BABFCEEG.html).

You can just search->text in IDA for:

`SVC             0x`

`SWI             0x`

Comment: Yes,but I looking for plugin that find all syscall and rename the functions name, or something like that, I don't want to do it manually

Comment: @wfj96649BcaooCom You could always script that. It's not exactly difficult.